# adjust the rows dynamically in paginator of primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using the primefaces datatable paginator. I have fixed the to no of rows to 15. This correctly matches the my system resolution. But users are using monitors with different(bigger) resolutions. The no of rows in this case will be less and space will be displayed at the bottom.
Any way i can increase these rows dynamically based on screen resolution.
Below is the code I am using.

```
<p:dataTable var="order" value="#{orderdetails.orderDetailsList}" scrollable="true" styleClass="ui-dynamic-height" 
sortMode="multiple"  emptyMessage="" frozenColumns="1" resizableColumns="true" widgetVar="orderstatustable" 
liveResize="true" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
```

Any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Define two JSF inputHidden Fields say screenHeight, and screenWidth in your xhtml files
2.Calculate the computedHeight and computedWidth using javascript when page loads and store it into the hidden fields.
3.Automatically the value will be binded to the managedbean varaibles.
4.Write a method to return no of rows based on the screenHeight and screen width
5.Call that method via Expression Language in you JSF datatable rows attribute

Sample XHTML file follows

```html
 <h:head>

   <script type="text/javascript">
 
     function setResolution(){
     
  //Calculated the computedHeight and computedWidth from javascript
   document.getElementById('myForm:screenHeight').value = computedHeight;
          document.getElementById('myForm:screenWidth') .value=computedWidth;
    }
     
</script>
</h:head>

<h:body onload="setResolution();">

<h:form id="myForm">
<h:inputHidden id="screenHeight" value="#{managedBean.screenHeight}" />
<h:inputHidden id="screenWidth" value="#{managedBean.screenWidth}" />

   // call rows="#{managedBean.calculatedRows}" 
<p:dataTable var="order" value="#{orderdetails.orderDetailsList}" scrollable="true" styleClass="ui-dynamic-height" sortMode="multiple"  emptyMessage="" frozenColumns="1" resizableColumns="true" widgetVar="orderstatustable" liveResize="true" paginator="true" rows="#{managedBean.calculatedRows}" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false">
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>

</h:body>
```

Sample Managed Bean for your reference

```js
@ManagedBean
public class ManagedBean implements serilizable{

private float screenHeight;
private float screenWidth;
//gets and setters

private int calculatedRows(){
//Your business logic to return no of rows based on 
//screenHeight and screenWidth(resolution)
}


}
```